The compiled Go executable doesn't run on other machines
I have used go build -o program.exe to build an application, program.exe, on my computer. This executable, program.exe, runs without any issues on my own computer.
However, when I transfer program.exe to another computer and attempt to run it, I encounter an error message:
Exception 0xc0000005 0x8 0x0 0x0
PC=0x0

runtime.asmstdcall(0x22fcf8)
        GO_HOME/src/runtime/sys_windows_amd64.s:75 +0x7a fp
=0x22fc80 sp=0x22fc60 pc=0x46e1fa
rax     0x0
rbx     0xbe6498
rcx     0xc6c4e8
rdx     0x20
rdi     0x7fffffdd000
rsi     0x22fe78
rbp     0x22fdc0
rsp     0x22fc58
r8      0x0
r9      0x22fee8
r10     0x27fa2e8
r11     0xc000004000
r12     0x22fec8
r13     0x0
r14     0xbe5b20
r15     0x3
rip     0x0
rflags  0x10293
cs      0x33
fs      0x53
gs      0x2b

The error message contains a reference to the sys_windows_amd64.s file from my computer's Golang development environment. Why is this? Does this mean that the compiled exe file is not portable and can only be used on my computer?
My computer runs on Windows 11 and has a Golang development environment installed, while the other computer runs on Windows 7 and does not have a Golang development environment.
go.mod
module github.com/myprogram

go 1.22

require (
    github.com/getlantern/systray v1.2.2
    github.com/gorilla/websocket v1.5.1
    github.com/kerwin612/hybrid-launcher v0.0.5
    github.com/rakyll/statik v0.1.7
    github.com/tarm/serial v0.0.0-20180830185346-98f6abe2eb07
)

require (
    github.com/getlantern/context v0.0.0-20220418194847-3d5e7a086201 // indirect
    github.com/getlantern/errors v1.0.3 // indirect
    github.com/getlantern/golog v0.0.0-20230503153817-8e72de7e0a65 // indirect
    github.com/getlantern/hex v0.0.0-20220104173244-ad7e4b9194dc // indirect
    github.com/getlantern/hidden v0.0.0-20220104173330-f221c5a24770 // indirect
    github.com/getlantern/ops v0.0.0-20231025133620-f368ab734534 // indirect
    github.com/go-logr/logr v1.4.1 // indirect
    github.com/go-logr/stdr v1.2.2 // indirect
    github.com/go-stack/stack v1.8.1 // indirect
    github.com/oxtoacart/bpool v0.0.0-20190530202638-03653db5a59c // indirect
    go.opentelemetry.io/otel v1.21.0 // indirect
    go.opentelemetry.io/otel/metric v1.21.0 // indirect
    go.opentelemetry.io/otel/trace v1.21.0 // indirect
    go.uber.org/multierr v1.11.0 // indirect
    go.uber.org/zap v1.26.0 // indirect
    golang.org/x/net v0.19.0 // indirect
    golang.org/x/sys v0.15.0 // indirect
)

My program depends on the github.com/getlantern/systray library, so I have provided two .syso files in the compilation root directory: myprogram_386.syso, myprogram_amd64.syso
I'm still confused and would appreciate any help. Thank you!

that's a stack trace and GO_HOME/src/runtime/sys_windows_amd64.s:75  is simply the line where the issue happens, for easier debugging. It has nothing to do with the development environment dependency

@phuclv The exception was thrown when I ran it on computer B, but the file path of computer A appeared in the exception stack trace. This alone should indicate the problem, right?

@KerwinBryant: "the other computer runs on Windows 7" Go 1.21 Release Notes: "As announced in the Go 1.20 release notes, Go 1.21 requires at least Windows 10 or Windows Server 2016; support for previous versions has been discontinued."

debug information obviously is generated on the building machine, so the paths are valid there, but it has nothing to do with the running machine. It's for debugging only, because how on earth can running depends on a source file? It's not a dependency

As noted by @rocka2q in the comments, the issue is indeed caused by a version incompatibility of Go.

Go 1.21 Release Notes: "As announced in the Go 1.20 release notes, Go 1.21 requires at least Windows 10 or Windows Server 2016; support for previous versions has been discontinued."

thanks @rocka2q
